# restart a CDH5 cluster on EC2 saved as AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I have installed a simple 2 node cluster using the cloudera manager installer (cdh 5.3).
Everything seems to work fine.

Then I saved each node as an AMI.

Next I launched an instance of each image again, making sure the nic was in the same (private)subnet as the original cluster, using the same security group.

The nodes can ping each other, but the Cloudera manager can't seem to find the nodes any more. ("no heartbeat received").

When trying to add a new node to the cluster, using the IP's or FQDN it tells me that the node is already being managed.
I also can't seem to delete/remove from cluster/...

Am I missing something critical here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this seems to be failing are the host names.
When assigning a static private IP to an instance the hostname changes to ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.

Editing the hosts file didn't seem to help.

So I ditched the Cloudera manager installation as a whole.

Installing CDH (5.3) from packages seems to do the trick.

*note:* use private IP's and start the nodes with the same private IP's

A possible solution that I didn't try out since it works for me now with this installation could be to start of with assigning static private IP's when first launching the instance.